# Chromedriver with options and proxy. Adding mobile emulation

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the settings I use for ChromeDriver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
// Add the WebDriver proxy capability.
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("127.0.0.1:3128");
proxy.setSslProxy("127.0.0.1:3128");
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

// Add ChromeDriver-specific capabilities through
// ChromeOptions.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
options.addArguments("--disable-plugins-discovery");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);


driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But I also want to add mobile emulation. Based on what I read in the docs, Below is what I need

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
```

and then I would set it to capabilities like below

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

Then pass it to ChromeDriver. But if I set it to DesiredCapabilities , then my proxy and other options would no longer be applied to DesiredCapabilities.

How can I emulate a mobile while preserving my proxy and options settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in arguments into `chromeOptions` via key `args` and a `List<String>` arguments:

Combined with the `mobileEmulation` setting, this should preserve all your options settings.

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

// add this
chromeOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList("incognito", "disable-bundled-ppapi-flash",
    "disable-extensions", "profile-directory=Default", "disable-plugins-discovery",
    "start-maximized"));
```

Also your proxy settings should not be affected, you are calling `setCapability` on `ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY`, your `"proxy"` settings remain unchanged.

Comment: would it be possible to add an extension using the method you showed me?

Comment: You can do this in a similar manner, via key `extensions` and a `List<string>` arguments. Reference: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities